# Wordpress exclude pages plugin hack

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want the wordpress exclude pages plugin to work with my theme. Here is where my theme queries for all the pages and displays them all in a row on a single page.

```
$pagepull = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'page' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY menu_order", ARRAY_A);

foreach ($pagepull as $single_page){
    echo $single_page['post_content']; 
    // do other stuff too
}
```

Do you have any ideas on how to adjust the query to work with exclude pages? There isn't a function to get all pages is there? I know there is wp_list_pages() to get the list of pages but i'm not trying to display a nav here.

Would it be a better idea to do 2 queries, 1 where you get the list of pages, and then 2 query for that list? Not entirely sure how to do that, but an extra query sounds like a bad idea. Thoughts?

UPDATE:
from the answer below I have found this to work:

```
        $excluded = ep_get_excluded_ids();
        foreach ($excluded as $removepage){
            echo "";
            $limits .= " AND id != $removepage";
        }
        $pagepull = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'page' AND post_status = 'publish' $limits ORDER BY menu_order", ARRAY_A);
```

Now, for safety sake, how do I test to see if a plugin's function exists? Sense I rely on ep_get_excluded_ids(); from the Exclude Plugin to be installed.

UPDATE2: - removed - (i had a simple misspelling in this problem, never mind this)

Comment: How about using get_pages? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to return all but specified pages (and you don't want the formatting of `wp_list_pages()`), you could do:

```
$excArr = array(5,7,10);

foreach($excArr as $p)
    $limits .= " AND id != $p";

$pagepull = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'page' AND post_status = 'publish' $limits ORDER BY menu_order", ARRAY_A);
```

Another option would be to use `wp_list_pages()` and style the `<li>` and `<ul>` elements so they don't look like a list.

Comment: Can I get ['post_content'] from wp_list_pages()?

Comment: @Dave, No. Here's the man page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

Comment: Sweet, your solution works. Question 1: Doesn't the "foreach()" need {}'s ? And question 2, how do I include a simple if statement to make sure the function "ep_get_excluded_ids()" (in other words: the plugin) exists?

Comment: Answer #1: you don't need `{}` if the inside of the loop is only one line long. This also goes for `while` and `for` and other control structures too...

Comment: Answer #2: `if(function_exists('ep_get_excluded_ids')) { }`

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help! Also learned something new with Answer #1.